# Program Counter

Tags: processor

A program counter is a register that contains the address of the instruction being executed at the current time. Data, instruction and address are stored in ROM memory.

How does program counter operate?

I am reading this page [enter link description here](http://wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/Program_Counter)

I have few basic questions 
plan : program counter design 
I have to make loadable program counter 
whenever we design circuit we should know some basic
what should I know ?
which component I need to design basic PC ?
I know we add some mux but I don't understand how to start ?

Comment: It's just a regular binary counter, used to address the Program Store memory. Increment and Load signals come from the state machine that manages the other internal CPU resources (e.g. microcode). Take a look at some of the CPU projects on opencores.org for implementation details in VHDL/Verilog.

Comment: It's not really a counter - sometimes it counts, sometimes it is loaded, or added/subtracted to. Loadable counters exist, but few that can accommodate the loads corresponding to absolute program address changes, variable increments from variable length instructions and adds from relative address changes.

Comment: How does we make program counter.which Ic or component  should I used to make program counter

Answer (score 4):

The program counter (PC) is a binary counter that contains the address of the next instruction to be executed.  For this reason it is sometimes referred to as the instruction address register.  The PC is generally incremented just after the current instruction has been fetched.

Assuming a byte-addressable memory, on a RISC machine, where all the instructions are the same length (e.g. 32-bits on the MIPS-based PIC32), then the PC will be incremented by the instruction length (in this case four) after each instruction.  On a CISC processor, like the Intel x86 series, where the instructions can be variable length, then the PC will be incremented by the size of the current instruction.

Some program memories are word-addressable only, and instructions may only be one or two words longs, in which case the PC would be incremented by 1 or 2 respectively.

Programs execute linearly, unless a jump instruction is executed.  An unconditional jump always modifies the PC; a conditional jump modifies the PC only if the condition stated in the conditional instruction (such as, reg n is 0).

A jump instruction may either contain the address of the next instruction to be executed, in which case the PC is overwritten with the address in the instruction, or it may contain a signed relative value, which is added to the current PC value to obtain the next address.  Sometimes the latter are referred to as branch instructions.  They may be either unconditional or conditional.

For the PIC32 MIPS architecture, jump instructions save two bits in the address field of the instruction by only specifying the target address divided by four, since all instructions are known to be on a four-byte boundary.  In fact, if an attempt was made to jump to an address that was not on a four-byte boundary, a hardware exception would be raised.

A call or jump to subroutine instruction also modifies the PC (usually the address of the subroutine is contained in the call instruction, although some processors implement a relative branch to subroutine instruction as well).  The main difference between a jump instruction and a subroutine call is the the PC is usually saved on a *stack*, and at the end of the subroutine, a *return* instruction is executed that retrieves this value and places it in the the PC, so the program resumes executing immediately after the original subroutine call instruction.

Often on smaller microcontrollers, only a 16-bit program address space will be implemented, limiting the program to 65536 bytes.  If it is desired to go beyond this limit, then a paging scheme may be used, with (for example) a 16K "window" reserved in the 64K address space, extended to 128K bytes by providing eight 16K pages.  A special "paging register" is used to select which page is active.